# stats.rv_continuous slow when when using custom pdf

Tags: python, random, scipy, statistics

Ultimately I am trying to visualise the copula between two PDFs which are estimated from data (both via a KDE). Suppose, for one of the KDEs, I have discrete `x,y` data sorted in a tuple called `data`. I need to generate random variables with this distribution in order to perform the probability integral transform (and ultimately to obtain the uniform distribution). My methodology to generate random variables is as follows:

```
import scipy.stats as st
from scipy import interpolate, integrate

pdf1 = interpolate.interp1d(data[0], data[1])

class pdf1_class(st.rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self,x):
        return pdf1(x)

pdf1_rv = pdf1_class(a = data[0][0], b= data[0][-1], name = 'pdf1_class')

pdf1_samples = pdf1_rv.rvs(size=10000)
```

However, this method is extremely slow. I also get the following warnings:

> IntegrationWarning: The maximum number of subdivisions (50) has been achieved.
>     If increasing the limit yields no improvement it is advised to analyze 
>     the integrand in order to determine the difficulties.  If the position of a 
>     local difficulty can be determined (singularity, discontinuity) one will 
>     probably gain from splitting up the interval and calling the integrator 
>     on the subranges.  Perhaps a special-purpose integrator should be used.
>     warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
>
> IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents 
>     the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be 
>     underestimated.
>     warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)

Is there a better way to generate the random variables?

Comment: Per [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html), speed can be increased by overriding `_logpdf, _cdf, _logcdf, _ppf, _rvs, _isf, _sf, _logsf`. To speed up `rvs`, it [may be sufficient to override `_ppf`](https://gist.github.com/josef-pkt/2864348) (the percent point fuction, inverse of cdf).

Comment: I overrode `_cdf` which made no appreciable difference. I then overrode `_ppf` as well and now 10000 samples is instant. Thank you. Do you want to make this an answer and I will accept?

Comment: Since you've put in the work to implement `_ppf`, I think you'd be in the best position to write a great answer. ([Answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is not only acceptable, it's encouraged.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per suggestion by @unutbu I implemented `_cdf` and `_ppf`, which makes the calculation of 10000 samples instantaneous. To do this I added the following to the above code:

```
discrete_cdf1 = integrate.cumtrapz(y=data[1], x = data[0])
cdf1 = interpolate.interp1d(data[0][1:], discrete_cdf1)
ppf1 = interpolate.interp1d(discerete_cdf1, data[0][:-1])
```

I then add the following two methods to `pdf1_class`

```
def _cdf(self,x):
    return cdf1(x)

def _ppf(self,x):
    return ppf1(x)
```

Comment: it seems first x should be skipped, not the last one: cdf1 = interpolate.interp1d(data[0][1:], discrete_cdf1)

Comment: Good spot, will amend.

Comment: You could also use `initial = 0` as a kwarg in `cumtrapz` I suppose. This would negate the need to reduce the size of the data vector by 1.

Comment: also for ppf ) ppf1 = interpolate.interp1d(discerete_cdf1, data[0][1:])